# Object can't get the right value of its property

Tags: interrupt, class

I'm doing a program for a robot and I got stuck at a weird problem:
I have classes defined for my robot's internals, for example for a `StepMotor`. I also defined a class for a `Controller`, which is going to control the speed of each `StepMotor`.

Here's a fragment of my code:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Tone.h>
    #include <Wire.h>   
    #include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

    /SILNIKI KROKOWE:
    class StepMotor: public Device
    {
        public:    
            int motorPin;
            int dirPin;
            int sleepPin;
            int ForwardState;
            volatile double Speed;
            volatile int ControlValue;  //the value sent to the motor
            int MaxControlValue = 4000; //maximum ControlValue
            String Name;

            void Init ( void )
            {     
                //init
            }

            void SetSpeed ( int speed )
            {
              toneObject.play(speed);
            }

            void SetMode(bool IsOn)
            {
              if (IsOn)
                digitalWrite(sleepPin, HIGH);
              else
                digitalWrite(sleepPin, LOW);
            }

            void SetDirection ( Dir direction )
            {
    //code for setting direction
            }

        private:
          Tone toneObject;            
    };

    StepMotor motor_right;
    StepMotor motor_left;


    class Controller
    {
      public:
        ControllerType controllerType;
        double Kp;
        double Ki;
        double Kd;
        double Tp; //czas próbkowania
        volatile double e;
        volatile double e_old;
        volatile double P_result;
        volatile double I_result;
        volatile double D_result;
        StepMotor Motor;

        int Calculate ()
        {
          int Result;
     //Serial.print(Motor.Speed); HERE's THE PROBLEM
    /********************************
    /********************************
    /*******************************     
          e = MoveOrder::speed - Motor.Speed;  //Motor.Speed is always 0.00, although it's not true

             //the rest is not important
        }

        void Reset()
        {
          //reset procedure
        }

    };



    Controller controller_right;
    Controller controller_left;

    setup()
    {
       controller_right.Motor = motor_right;
       controller_left.Motor = motor_left;
    }

    ISR(TIMER5_COMPA_vect)
    {
        motor_right.ControlValue = controller_right.Calculate();
        motor_left.ControlValue = controller_left.Calculate();
        motor_right.SetSpeed(motor_right.ControlValue);
        motor_left.SetSpeed(motor_left.ControlValue);

    }
```

I have cut the less important parts. The rest works properly, because my robot can drive when I use `SetSpeed(somevalue);` The only problem is that place where I need to read current speed of my motor. 
In the `Controller` class, there's `Calculate()` method. In that method I want to calculate `e = MoveOrder::speed - Motor.Speed;` Unfortunately it can't be calculated properly, because Motor.Speed ALWAYS is `0.00` (when I display it with `Serial.print(Motor.Speed)` I see `0.00` all the time). It's very strange, because when I display speed of each motor (`Serial.print(right_motor.Speed)` or `Serial.print(left_motor.Speed)`) the value is correct (when the wheels are spinning, value is not 0.00).

The speed calculations are in a different function, which I didn't present here, because it would be too long - I'm sure it works, because, as I said, I can get speed values properly.

As you can see in `setup()`, I set each contorller's Motor porperty to the correct object.
I also used volatile keyword for the properties that are used in the interrupt.

What is wrong with my code?

If the code I provided isn't enough, here's the full version:
https://1drv.ms/t/s!Atl-jM_xUkz1hc1f-qYYotj-pJIgUw

I'm not sure if anyone would want to dive into it, because it's not so short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: `controller_right.Motor = motor_right;` makes a copy of `motor_right`. So you don't have the same class instance.

Basically `Controller controller_right;` calls default constructor which includes also default constructor for the `StepMotor`. And later all variables are copied into it by using default assigment operator, but still, it's not the same instance.

Comment: looks like you're right. So, I think I should: change StepMotor Motor in Controller class to StepMotor* Motor, to have a pointer. Then, in setup()   should do controller_right.Motor = &motor_right; and controller_left.Motor = &motor_left; Am I right?

Comment: @Loreno Or you can add `StepMotor & motor_right = controller_right.Motor;` after `controller_*` variable declaration. I guess, you can even skip these `motor_right`/`motor_left` variables as it's already in `Controller`

Comment: I need to be able to access motor_right and motor_left in other places (for exmple when I measure the speed of a motor and assign it to its Speed property). Your solution uses reference, right? i don't fully understand these, so I'm not sure what's the difference here. Today I can't check if the robot works correctly after applying those fixes, tomorrow I'll be able to do it and then I'll mark your answer as a proper one.

Comment: @Loreno It's basically an alias for referenced variable.